# How to sync wireframe/physics with dragged objects using three.js dragControls and ammo in aframe setup?

Tags: javascript, aframe

i am currently using the three js drag Controls in my a-frame setup and it is working well. I am also using ammo for physics and have attached to test object like so:

```
    <a-box  color="blue" click-drag  ammo-body="type: dynamic" ammo-shape="type: box;"  visible="true" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" position="-1.422 0.658 -2"></a-box>
```

the issue is, when dragging objects, they drag fine but the wireframe/physics is not moving at all so not in sync with objects. I would like to be able to add to objects and have them interact with other physics enabled objects in my scene such like these examples: https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/physics-2/

Not sure what to do as have tried numerous codes such as :

```
 var draggable = document.querySelector('[click-drag]');
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', function(dragInfo) {
    draggable.components['dynamic-body'].pause();
    });
    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', function(dragInfo) {
      var x = dragInfo.detail.velocity.x;
      var y = dragInfo.detail.velocity.y;
      var z = dragInfo.detail.velocity.z;

    draggable.components['dynamic-body'].play();
    draggable.body.velocity.set(x, y, z);
    console.log('drag end', dragInfo.detail.velocity);
    }); `
```

but no success. Would be happy to get some help. Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get [the component](https://github.com/jesstelford/aframe-click-drag-component) working with aframe 1.4.0?

Comment: Hi @PiotrAdamMilewski. i wasn't using that component but the three.dragControls from here https://github.com/SeregPie/aframe-drag-controls. I got it to work but when dragging objects with ammo, the wireframes/physics do not respond so stay static. I'm using ammo (hull) as it is better at creating shapes than cannon but i did try cannon and also the same issue. Would be good to have this working as can then interact with objects and have them collide in real time.